# fresh laravel throught docker installation failing by searching for octan

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail, laravel-octane

I run command to get new laravel 9 setup under docker with only mysql and redis containers by doing `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app??with=mysql,redis" | bash`, after that I run `cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up`, and for some reason my php-fpm container not running correctly, I'm getting error:

```
example-app-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-04 20:59:27,326 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 44
example-app-laravel.test-1  | 
example-app-laravel.test-1  |    ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "octane" namespace.  
example-app-laravel.test-1  | 
example-app-laravel.test-1  | 2022-08-04 20:59:28,193 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
```

but I do not use `octane` in this setup, I did not install it, I do not have it in `compose.json`. Okay to be clear I have another laravel project with `octane`,but it's not running, I have up and running only containers related to the current laravel setup, so why does it want `octane` from me? how can I run fresh laravel?

Comment: You need octane install

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I installed Octane in another Laravel project with sail and cannot start a fresh new Laravel project.

Solution: run `./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache` under the new project.

Try to start the server again `./vendor/bin/sail up`